# Fiximate replicate?

Tags: javascript, html, fix-protocol

I want to create something similar to fiximate but the thing I want to do different is filter by venue instead of FIX version.

Having downloaded the FIXImate for offline use to get an idea of the design. It seems as though the developers used a tool which parses the FIX XML and spits out html pages based on field tag and body.

Does anyone have access to such a tool? Is there another way to design something similar which is less complicated?

Thanks

Comment: Better then the Fiximate - www.interactivefix.com, you don't have to lookup tag by tag

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is not trivial. It is telling that there is a commercial product for this: https://fixspec.com/

Comment: The reason behind this is the many of the venues like to keep track of who's accessing their specs, mainly from an account management point of view. Very often the specs are only provided in PDF format, so extracting the information necessary is definitely not a simple job even once you have them. The chaps at FIXSpec are really filling a gap here.

Comment: Could you explain the difference bet ween Fiximate and Fixspec ?

Comment: Fiximate is a free browser-based tool for exploring FIX specs, provided by the Fix Protocol Ltd organization.  Fixspec is a commercial product for other (non-standard, custom) FIX specs.